# SQL merge into when 2 columns are unique

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to merge 2 tables `@UserIds` and `@Results` into `@Results` when 2 columns are unique

What I have so far

```
MERGE INTO @UserIds t
USING (SELECT
          CustomerIdentifier, SalesChannel_Id
       FROM @Results) AS s ON (s.CustomerIdentifier = t.CustomerIdentifier 
                               AND s.SalesChannel_Id = t.SalesChannel_Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CustomerIdentifier, SalesChannel_Id, Searched) 
    VALUES (s.CustomerIdentifier, s.SalesChannel_Id, 0);
```

The merge results in duplicate `CustomerIdentifier` and `SalesChannel_Id` values

E.g.

```
234@234.com.au  111 0
234@234.com.au  2   0
234@234.com.au  2   0
234@234.com.au  2   0
243@234.com.au  18  0
234@234.com.au  18  0
```

when it should only even contain

```
234@234.com.au  111 0
234@234.com.au  2   0
234@234.com.au  18  0
```

Comment: (1) Merge is not going to delete results from the first table if there are duplicates; (2) Perhaps the values have some subtle difference (such as unseen characters on the strings or 0.0000000 versus 0.000000001).

Comment: good point i best do some checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MERGE statement will insert any duplicate keys in @Results if they do not already exist in @UserIds, you can avoid this by adding a DISTINCT operator

```
MERGE INTO @UserIds t
USING (SELECT DISTINCT
    CustomerIdentifier,
    SalesChannel_Id
FROM @Results) as s 
ON (s.CustomerIdentifier = t.CustomerIdentifier and s.SalesChannel_Id = t.SalesChannel_Id )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CustomerIdentifier, SalesChannel_Id, Searched) 
    VALUES (s.CustomerIdentifier,s.SalesChannel_Id, 0);
```